# Azure Service Fabric Single Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

On Azure Currently I use "Cloud Service" to build salable apps. "Azure Service Fabric" looks like latest method of building apps on cloud. It is very good, however I am unable to create it with single virtual machine. It shows minimum of 5 VM's per type. Since I am creating a startup app, I am unable to use 5 VMs. Is it ok to use to "Cloud Service" then? I worried it is marked as "Classic" in new portal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service Fabric uses a cluster of nodes - that's fundamental to how it works. It uses the nodes to ensure reliability, scalability, etc.

If you just want to play around with and don't want to pay for the VMs you have 3 options:

- Install the Service Fabric SDK on your machine
- Install the Service Fabric SDK on a VM on Azure
- Use the Service Fabric Party Clusters - http://tryazureservicefabric.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/

Comment: As an unsupported, but feasible, way to get a publicly accessible POC up and running for more time than the party clusters, you can install the SDK on a single Azure VM. But as noted, this is then losing all the resiliency and reliability features.

Comment: Agreed - was tempted to put that down as a 3rd option but I figured it's obvious outcome of the first option + Azure IaS. I'll add it for clarity. Thanks Darran.

Comment: I actually don't want to change my code OR Deployment process in future when my app grows. That's why I am looking to use Service Fabric instead of cloud service now. Looks like cloud service is good for small starters (with 1 to 2 vm), and it is also scalable to multiple vm's. I thought service fabric would do the same but Looks like I have to stay with Cloud Service now (2 Web role + 1 worker role). May be I have to migrate to Service Fabric when my app grows. Thanks for suggesting Service Fabric SDK on VM. But I am not confident to select that option  due to complexity of managing them.

Answer (score 2):

The main benefits of a service fabric application are reliability, scalability, and low latency. By placing your application on a single VM, you would be reducing the reliability significantly. I believe that is why the minimum cluster size is 5 VMs.

However, the framework for service fabric is the same whether you are running on a local cluster or running in a distributed manner in a multi-VM cluster. When you press F5 in Visual Studio, a local "cluster" is created to simulate all 5 nodes on a single machine.

If you are trying to run your application with a minimal number of VMs (knowing you are sacrificing reliability), you could create a single VM and deploy the service fabric application locally. The VM will show up as a Classic VM, but when you are ready to commit to a cluster, the same application will easily deploy.